# Change Site Policy email notification template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, csom, site-collection, email-templates

I am trying to change the Site Policy email notification template that is sent before the site is deleted.

I am using a CSOM console application very similar to the one described in following post [Site Policy in SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/03/28/site-policy-in-sharepoint/)

I am testing this in SharePoint server 2013 and SharePoint Server 2016.

The new template is applied and the policies are using it.

The issue is that I cannot make the tokens for Site URL and Site Deletion date to work tried them as html comments like  and just {SiteUrl}, in both cases the tokens itself are in the email HTML that is being sent sent, unfortunately the tokens are not replaced with values. The full HTML template is below:

```
The Test site <!-- {SiteUrl} --> is set to expire on <!-- {SiteDeleteDate} --> . <br/>
```

If you have any questions or concerns, please contact your **admin**.

You can postpone the deleteion here:

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your text format of the mail.

1. If you are using Outlook client application: File -> Options -> Mail -> Compose messages > Change it to HTML format.
   [image]
2. If you are using Outlook Web App: Settings   -> Options -> settings -> mail -> Compose message in HTML format.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is irrelevant to the question. The tokens are not replaced by SharePoint when the deletion notification is send out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the placeholders from the article are wrong.

The correct placeholders are:

SiteUrl: 
Deletion Date: 
Mailbox ID:

http://www.sptrenches.com/2018/01/change-site-policy-template.html

After I clanged them everything is working as expected.